# How to position text at the top edge of a VegaLite chart?

Tags: visualization, vega-lite

I am trying to create a VegaLite chart with labelled highlighted areas which are specified in a separate dataset using `[min_x, max_x]` coordinates.

I've managed to highlight the area itself using a `rect` mark, but I'm struggling to properly position the label at the top edge of the chart.

This is the end result I'm trying to achieve. In this example I'm using the `dy` property of the `text` mark to position the label. Unfortunately this only works when the chart height is known in advance, which doesn't work for my use case.

[image: Desired result]

If there is a better way to achieve the result I want, please let me know. This is the Vegalite specification for the chart above, without previously mentioned `dy` property:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "datasets": {
    "test_data": [
      {"x": 0, "y": 1.5},
      {"x": 5, "y": 2},
      {"x": 9, "y": 4},
      {"x": 14, "y": 0}
    ],
    "highlight_data": [
      {"from_x": 2.3, "to_x": 3, "label": "AAA"},
      {"from_x": 6.3, "to_x": 8, "label": "BBB"}
    ]
  },
  "data": {"name": "test_data"},
  "layer": [
    {
      "data": {"name": "highlight_data"},
      "transform": [
        {"calculate": "(datum.from_x + datum.to_x) / 2", "as": "mean_x"}
      ],
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": {"type": "rect", "opacity": 0.3},
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "from_x", "type": "quantitative"},
            "x2": {"field": "to_x"},
            "color": {"value": "#fcfc00"}
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {"type": "text"},
          "encoding": {
            "text": {"field": "label"},
            "x": {"field": "mean_x", "type": "quantitative"}
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "line"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative", "title": "X Label"},
        "y": {"field": "y", "type": "quantitative", "title": "Y Label"}
      }
    }
  ],
  "title": "Title",
  "width": 800,
  "height": 500
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference height inside an expression to make it dynamic.

> "dy": { "expr": "-height + (height/2) -10"}

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "datasets": {
    "test_data": [
      {"x": 0, "y": 1.5},
      {"x": 5, "y": 2},
      {"x": 9, "y": 4},
      {"x": 14, "y": 0}
    ],
    "highlight_data": [
      {"from_x": 2.3, "to_x": 3, "label": "AAA"},
      {"from_x": 6.3, "to_x": 8, "label": "BBB"}
    ]
  },
  "data": {"name": "test_data"},
  "layer": [
    {
      "data": {"name": "highlight_data"},
      "transform": [
        {"calculate": "(datum.from_x + datum.to_x) / 2", "as": "mean_x"}
      ],
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": {"type": "rect", "opacity": 0.3},
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "from_x", "type": "quantitative"},
            "x2": {"field": "to_x"},
            "color": {"value": "#fcfc00"}
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {"type": "text", "dy": { "expr": "-height + (height/2) -10"}},
          "encoding": {
            "text": {"field": "label"},
            "x": {"field": "mean_x", "type": "quantitative"}
            
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "line"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative", "title": "X Label"},
        "y": {"field": "y", "type": "quantitative", "title": "Y Label"}
      }
    }
  ],
  "title": "Title",
  "width": 800,
  "height": 500
}
```